Differences in Auction/Foreclosures/Foreclosure Auctions
In the residential housing market, my understanding is that there are three types of property distress:

Auction
Foreclosures
Foreclosure Auctions

How are they exactly different? My understanding is that most foreclosures go through auctions, so it is reasonable to say most foreclosed properties undergo foreclosure auctions.
But, what would be a reason, if there is any, to get a standalone auction without foreclosure status?

Auction is just a way to conduct a sale. Most real estate properties are sold through auctions, most of them closed auctions (your regular listings and bids).
Foreclosure is a process of a lender taking over a property securing a debt in order to recover a debt. Usually in the context of mortgaged properties. For cars, it's called "repossession", but is essentially the same. Foreclosures can be triggered by tax debts or HOA debts as well.
Foreclosure auction (or, more precisely, "trustee sale") is a process when a foreclosed property is being sold to cover the debt. This is usually (but not always) done as an open auction. Estate sales are also sometimes conducted as open auctions.

Thanks for the answer! A question -- in your response, auction sounds like not a distress event for a property, but my understanding is that it is. Most residential properties are sold in sequential bargaining (e.g., as offers come in) though recently this has changed after the covid and supply crunch. Can you clarify what you mean by "most...are sold through auctions?", because this sounds unusual to me and not a distress event.

@FrankSwanton auction is a sale even where bidders submit bids within a given time frame and the best bid wins (by whatever definition of "best" for the seller). While technically real estate doesn't have to be sold this way, in practice it almost always is. Especially in areas which are "seller markets".

Most real estate properties are not sold through auctions. The process is superficially similar, in that potential buyers provide bids, but there area big differences. For example the seller can select any bid; they can also reject all bids and ask for higher ones; they can do that only for selected buyers. It's also rare that sellers ask for all bids by a particular time - usually people submit offers whenever they want, and the seller accepts or rejects them.

There are basically three ways to sell a house: 1. The most common way is to hire a realtor and seek bids on the house. The first reasonable bid, you negotiate with the potential buyer until you either make a deal or one of you gives up. 2. Private sale. Fairly rare. You make a deal with a buyer directly. This is, perhaps, becoming more common with "cash for home" companies. 3. Auction. You announce an auction and potential buyers show up to bid.
I see another poster referred to option #1 as an "auction". Well sort of, but I've never called that an auction and I've never heard anyone else call that an auction. Maybe that's terminology used by realtors or some other profession, but it's not the common terminology.
Anyway, any of those methods can be used to sell a foreclosed property, and any of those methods can be used for a "regular" property sale.
I once bought a house that had been foreclosed. The bank sold it just like an ordinary homeowner would sell a house: they listed it with a realtor and sought offers, and when I made an offer they negotiated with me. The only difference was, my realtor told me that the bank would not negotiate about repairs or other conditions I might have before buying. The only thing they'd negotiate on is price. So if the house needed repairs -- which it did -- I should estimate the cost of the repairs and subtract that from my offer. Which I did, and I bought a house pretty cheap.
Auctions are, I think, typically "as is" because it's not practical to compare bids with different conditions. If person A bids $150,000 as is, and person B bids $170,000 but demands the kitchen cabinets be upgraded, which is the higher bid? Hard to say.

It depends on the area of the country.  Even during the downturn, very few homes in my area went to auction that were foreclosed.  Distressed properties are typically listed with a relator and may have some strange closing conditions.
One such property would not pay the buyer's agent's commission, the buyer had to come up with that money and had some other conditions about financing.
Another notified local agents that a decision was to be made by a certain date, and all would be buyers should put in a bid.  The bank was not happy with the bids and handled the sale itself.  The bank brought in contractors to make the trashed home a non-distressed property and sold it as a "recent remodel" and got market rates for it.
So, it all depends on your area and here in central Florida trying to find a distressed home is simply unrealistic these days.
